# Should accepted answers be changed for questions closed as "not a question"?

Tags: discussion

In my reputation history I see a shift from an answer being unaccepted for [PHP script to remove e-mail addresses from a comma-separated list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8681448/816584) which was closed as "not a question".

My answer may not have directly answered the question being asked, but it was surprising to see that kind of activity on a closed question. As I understood closing a question prevents new answers from being submitted. If no new answers are being submitted (newly accepted answer was submitted before closed), what would cause the accepted answer to change? I could understand logic supporting removing accepted answers on the grounds of how can you have an answer for something that is not a question.

In this particular case the recently accepted answer came from the question as it evolved into an answer. If a moderator were to derive an accepted answer from the question as a community wiki answer, should the question not be reopened? If it can be answered does that not make it a question?

Comment: Users should accept whichever helped them the most.

Comment: It may be helpful to include a link to that question in your question here for context.

Comment: @Anonymous thanks, I added a link to an example question I'm talking about. I'm just not sure what it is that I'm asking now.

Comment: "should the accepted answer be made the community wiki and edited to reflect the collaborative answer" Isn't the accepted answer already a community wiki?

Comment: Does not really look like a good question... needs polish.

Comment: @Anonymous My answer was accepted before the question was closed. I don't think my answer properly answered the question, but should it have been changed after the question was closed?

Comment: @Deduplicator My question here doesn't properly reflect what I'm asking, I'm in the process of figuring out how to improve it.

Comment: @SteveBuzonas I cleaned up the question to represent what I believe you are asking.  Feel free to make changes or completely revert the question to it's original form if you wish.

Comment: @Anonymous thanks, I think that more clearly expresses what I had initially wanted to get across, but I'm thinking about rewriting the question to better reflect `Should accepted answers be changed for questions closed as "not a question"?`

Comment: @SteveBuzonas Go ahead, it's your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted answer can be changed anytime by the OP of the question. This is their decision, no-one else's, and they are not obligated to mark any answer as accepted.

> "Should questions closed as not a question be allowed to have an accepted answer?"

Yes, absolutely. Just because it is closed for any reason it doesn't mean that someone wasn't able to help the OP. It's also possible that questions don't get closed till some considerable time later, by which time it has an accepted answer. Removing that accepted answer both punishes the person who answered (they lose rep and other metrics used for badges), and it replaces certainty with uncertainty (i.e. which answer did the OP find useful/helpful?).

> "After a question is closed should the accepted answer be allowed to change?"

The OP and privileged users can still edit a question after it is closed, so it makes sense that the OP can also do something like change which answer is accepted.

Comment: I recently rewrote my question, I guess I'm looking for clarification on the processes and the system. "Should questions closed as not a question be allowed to have an accepted answer?" and "After a question is closed should the accepted answer be allowed to change?"

Comment: @SteveBuzonas I've updated my answer to (hopefully) better answer your updated questions.